# Trying to get a list of team names a member is a part of via comparing 2 sql tables

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to Get the users teams he is a part of to compare the 2 tables

DB TABLES:

```
CREATE TABLE `teams` (
  `teamid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `teamname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `teamdesc` longtext,
  `founder` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `dateformed` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`teamid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `teammembers` (
  `teamid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `member` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `rank` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`teamid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Current function i have to do stuff:

```
/* removeProject */
function getTeamNames($id){
    global $session, $database;
    $link = $database->connection;
    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT teamname FROM teams WHERE teamid=$id");
    $stmt->execute();
    $r = $stmt->fetch();
    return array('teams'=>$r['teamname']);
}
```

Query to get the team names:

```
$link = $database->connection;

 try{
    $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $q = "SELECT * FROM teammembers WHERE member=:un";
    $prep = $link->prepare($q);
    $array = array(
        ':un' => $user
    );
    $prep->execute($array);
}catch(PDOException $error){
    echo($error);
}
```

Then the info to display the data:

```
<select multiple class="form-control">
    <?php
    while($tid = $prep->fetch()){
        $teams = $database->getTeamNames($tid['teamid']);
        echo ("<option>$teams</option>");
    } ?>
</select>
```

Its only displaying the data as "Array"

UPDATE!!!

This is how i fixed it :)

```
while($tid = $prep->fetch()){
    $teams = $database->getTeamNames($tid['teamid']);
    //echo var_dump($teams);
    $team = $teams['teams'];
        echo ("<option>$team</option>");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `function getTeamNames($id)` returns an associative array that's why you are not getting the results.

Your loop should look something like

```
<?php

while($tid = $prep->fetch()){
    $teams = $database->getTeamNames($tid['teamid']);
    foreach($teams['teams'] as $team){
        echo ("<option>$teams</option>");
    }
} 

?>
```

Comment: This is returning empty results for some reason

Comment: Try doing a var_dump on $teams => var_dump($teams); and check the results.

Comment: The Error
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct, you returned the data as array (`return array('teams'=>$r['teamname']);`)

So when you echo the data, use `echo("<option>".$teams['teams']."</option>")` or dont return result as an array.